# Question has been migrated to an other website

Tags: support, migration

I posted my question on Serverfault.com on a day back. URL: [Access Remote files through http path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80830/access-remote-files-through-http-path).

But I noticed after a day, a notification alert shown me that "**Your question "Access Remote files through http path" was migrated to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.**"

I don't know who was the user migrated it or is it a decision from stackoverflow commitee. Not confirmed.

Kindly suggest what could be the reason. I also didn't found any suitable answer for the above question. So I need the help in which stackoverflow account I should posted this question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It was migrated by five ordinary users, you can see it [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/518633/access-remote-files-through-http-path?noredirect=1). One of them is "Jenny D" who also posted comments on your question so ask him/her directly e.g. "@Jenny why did you migrate this?"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I noticed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is better suited for another site on the Stack Exchange site then it is migrated to that site so that it has more chances of receiving better answers. So in a way question migration is for your own good.

Who can migrate a question? A site moderator can do this. Other alternate is that if 5 users, who have [relevant privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions), vote to migrate a particular question then it will be migrated.